# Django decorator to redirect to same page?

Tags: django

When a user tries to access a non permitted page, whats the right thing to do ?

```
First option: Redirect to the same page they came from 
Second Option: Redirect to error page saying permission denied or not found
Third Option: Redirect to login page
```

I have created a decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME

def is_student(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: (u.is_authenticated and u.role == 'role1'),
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

So the above works and redirects to login if we give login_url ! How to redirect to same page from users came or which option is best ?

Comment: To redirect the user to the previous url use : request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'). If it exist then return the user back. If not take him to the login may be !

Comment: What if HTTP_REFERER is disabled on browser

Comment: take him to the home page if so